# Does IsValid() protect from XSS?

Tags: validation, email, url, coldfusion, xss

Does using [IsValid()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fb9.html) to validate an email address or a URL format protect from XSS? Does it negate XSS when other formats are specified?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A valid URL can still contain an attack vector:

```
<!--- No on CF9 --->
<cfoutput>#isValid("url", "http://www.mydomain.com/products/products.asp?productid=123; DROP TABLE Products")#</cfoutput>

<!--- Yes on CF9: hex encoded ';DROP TABLE Products' --->
<cfoutput>#isValid("url", "http://www.mydomain.com/products/products.asp?productid=123%3B%20%44%52%4F%50%20%54%41%42%4C%45%20%50%72%6F%64%75%63%74%73")#</cfoutput>
```

Granted the above is not an XSS attack, but it could be changed to instead update columns with an attack.

Email validation appears to prevent [the attacks I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923594/valid-email-addresses-xss-and-sql-injection).

As a generalization, `isValid()` helps prevent XSS attacks when the datatype is finite - integers, SSNs, UUIDs, etc.. however, [there's a laundry list of documented potential attacks](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) against fields whose only datatype per se is 'string'. In that case, `isValid()` is of no help, rather [OWASP's AntiSamy](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project) is a useful tool for this purpose that traverses the DOM and removes anything not whitelisted.

[Best regex to catch XSS (Cross-site Scripting) attack (in Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723/best-regex-to-catch-xss-attack-in-java) provides a lot of useful information on the general topic of XSS prevention.

And finally to belabor the point, use:

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="..." value="...">
```

[to protect queries](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html).

**Update**

Last, but not least, [OWASP XSS Cheat Sheet](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet): best set of heuristics out there for processing input to prevent XSS.